# Web-service для начинающих

Tags: веб-программирование, service

Всем приветик. 
 Столкнулась с проблемой и уже неделю не могу ее решить. 
 Есть веб-сервис 
[Holidays](http://www.xmethods.com/ve2/ViewList...0-8287C330F353)

http://www.holidaywebservice.com/default.aspx

WSDL http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Hol...vice.asmx?WSDL

Нужно создать к нему 3 небольших (даже чисто символических) запроса : Soap запрос и http post, http get запросы.
 Буду благодарна за помощь бедной студентке.

Comment: А вы что-то сами пытались сделать? Расскажите, что именно у вас не получилось. (Не в общем «HTTP POST не работает», а например «на каждый второй HTTP POST приходит код 404»: чем больше подробностей, тем лучше.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте описание любого метода [здесь](http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx), например [GetCountriesAvailable](http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?op=GetCountriesAvailable). Там будут примеры всех ваших вариантов запросов.

Comment: Спасибо. 
Еще возник вопрос. в примерах, которые нам дали запросы в формате saz. 
чем его открыть или записать? 
в Fiddler же нельзя такие запросы писать ручками

Comment: @няшка_милашка saz открывается fiddler'ом как file - load archive.  
И в fiddler'е можно писать такие запросы. Закладка Composer. Soap запросы отправляются POST'ом. Get и Post варианты соответственно get и post методами. Кроме того, вы можете открыть в браузере описание метода, нажать Invoke и в fiddler'е посмотреть что и как отправляется и принимается (закладка Insectors). Fiddler должен суметь перехватить этот запрос, если не смог, настройте в вашем браузере proxy localhost:8888, тогда запрос точно будет перехвачен.